# Angular 10 - What is a Error: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Window -> Window -> Window]

Tags: angular, angular10

I am trying to access the window object in Angular via a service that can be injected.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

function _window():any {
  return window;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class WindowRef {
  get nativeWindow():any{
    return _window()
  }
}
```

I tried to create a injectable service and trying it to include in App Module but looks like there is some error. Tried to add as

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
```

In service file and also tried the other way around in app.module as

```
import { WindowRef } from './_windowRef.service';
```

and then

```
providers: [WindowRef],
```

ERROR
Error: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Window -> Window -> Window]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for Window!

. [this is the link to stackblitz - code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pxvvbe?devtoolsheight=33&embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts&hideNavigation=1).

Can you please let know as to what I am missing here or how can I get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a WindowRef service available, but how is Angular supposed to know to use it for Window? WindowRef != Window.

The usual way is to use a factory provider with an [injection token](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens) like this:

```
export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken<Window>('window');

export const WindowProvider: FactoryProvider = {
  provide: WINDOW,
  useFactory: getWindow
};

export function getWindow(): Window {
  return window;
}
```

Then provide it in your module:

```
providers: [ WindowProvider ]
```

And use `@Inject` for your component:

```
constructor( @Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window )
```

Comment: Thanks Roddy, I will checkout the injection token part

Answer (score 0):

got a easy way out. Directly provide the window object as

```
providers: [
    { provide: Window, useValue: window }
]
```

and access anywhere as

```
constructor(private window: Window) {
    // ...
}
```